# replacing html helpers by tag helpers

Tags: razor, view, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper, tag-helpers

I want to replace html helpers by tag helpers in View.

For this I replacing: `@model IEnumerable<Person>`

by `@model IList<Person>`

and `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)`

by `<label asp-for="@Model[0].Name"></label>`

but what I should use instead: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)`?

`<input asp-for="@item.Name"  readonly />` ?

It doesn't look right.

**UPDATE**: Just to clarify question: `@Html.DisplayNameFor` and `<label asp-for` both generate labels in html.

`@Html.DisplayFor` generates just text. Which tag helper can replace it? I don't want to use `input` just to show text.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `IList` then you can access the property both ways.

```
@model IList<WebApp.Models.Person>

<input type="text" asp-for="@Model[0].Name" />

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <input type="text" asp-for="@item.Name" readonly/>

}
```

and if you used `IEnumerable`, you need to call `ToList` method to access the properties without using `foreach`

```
@model IList<WebApp.Models.Person>
@{
var model2 = Model.ToList();
}

<input type="text" asp-for="@model2[0].Name" />

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <input type="text" asp-for="@item.Name" readonly/>
}
```

Comment: question is: should I use input just to show info? it generates textbox in html.

Comment: I want the same result as @Html.DisplayFor, but using tag helper.

Comment: For displaying info you can use HTML tags with razor like this.
`<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <li>@item.Name</li>
}
</ul>`